# Ecommerce item sales forecasting with pandas and statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I want to forecast item sales (number of sales for each product) with pandas and statsmodel for an ecommerce business. Because item sales is a count dependent variable I'm assuming a Poisson modeling would work best.

In an ideal world the model will be used to decide on which products to use in ads (increasing product views) and also to decide on deciding price points (changing prices) to result in best performance/profitability.

So far so good, however when I try:

```
...
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
...
result = smf.poisson(formula="Item_Sales ~ Product_Detail_Views + Variant_Price + C(Product_Type)", data=df).fit()
```

I get:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  return -np.dot(L*X.T, X)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal
  return mu >= 0
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  oldparams) > tol))
```

And a table full of NaNs

If I use OLS with the same dataset:

```
result = smf.ols(formula="Item_Sales ~ Product_Detail_Views + Variant_Price + C(Product_Type)", data=df).fit()
```

I get an R-squared of 0.809 so data is good. The model isn't as usable though as I get negative predictions which are obviously not possible (you cannot have negative sales of items).

How can I make the Poisson model work?

Comment: If you buy a TV from a store today, and return it tomorrow, then a prediction of -1 for tomorrow starts to sound pretty good.

Comment: You raise a good point; "for tomorrow" assumes time is a factor in the analysis while it is not. If you take time out of equation, worst you can have is 0 net sales (excluding theft which is out of scope).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a data problem. Since no sample data is shown, cannot be sure. You can try using GLM with family Poisson or GEE with family Poisson

example:

```
smf.glm('sedimentation ~ C(control_grid)', data=df, families=sm.families.Poisson)
```